# Is there a way to block the flexible update flow monits?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates, google-play-services, application-autoupdate

There are apps I don't want to update for some reason, like missing features, new unwanted features, or tons of video ads with newer versions. Often when I launch some apps, I get the monit asking me to update such an app. As I found out, it's so called "[flexible update flow](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates)" that came with Android 5.0 (API v21).
Is there a way to block it without patching such an app? Like blocking some Google service/app drawing on top?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this feature is available on 5.0. But it has been available for a while. You can disable updates per App.

1. Go to PlayStore
2. Select Manage Apps tab
3. Select the required App
4. Press on 3 dots on top right corner
5. Uncheck the box for `Enable Auto Update`

It may not stop the message from all apps.